# (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, spyder

I recently decided to give VS Code a try (previously I mainly did write python code in Spyder or Jupyter Notebooks). When I run the code I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Coding\BB tracking\BBtracking.py", line 103, in <module>
    BBtracking(file_path)
  File "c:\Users\Coding\BB tracking\BBtracking.py", line 20, in BBtracking
    r = cv2.selectROI(frame)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I don't understand the error. The code is supposed to load a video, then you can select with the mouse an area that you want to track, and get the tracked output as a video again. In Sypder the code is running without any issues.

Code:

```
def BBtracking(video_file):
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    # Load video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

    # Define output video properties
    output_file = 'output.avi'
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

    # Create VideoWriter object
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, fourcc, fps, frame_size)

    # Select ROI
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    r = cv2.selectROI(frame)

    # Initialize tracker
    tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
    tracker.init(frame, r)

    # Initialize variables
    positions = []
    speeds = []

    # Create blank image for line overlay
    overlay = np.zeros_like(frame)

    # Process video frame by frame
    while True:
        # Read frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        # Track object
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Draw bounding box and center point
        if ok:
            # Convert bounding box to integers
            bbox = np.int0(bbox)

            # Draw bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[0] + bbox[2], bbox[1] + bbox[3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # Calculate center point
            cx = bbox[0] + bbox[2] // 2
            cy = bbox[1] + bbox[3] // 2

            # Draw center point
            cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)

            # Save position
            positions.append((cx, cy))

            # Draw line to previous center point
            if len(positions) > 1:
                cv2.line(overlay, positions[-1], positions[-2], (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Calculate speed
            if len(positions) > 1:
                distance = np.sqrt((positions[-1][0] - positions[-2][0]) ** 2 + (positions[-1][1] - positions[-2][1]) ** 2)
                speed = distance / (1 / cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
                speeds.append(speed)

        # Add line overlay to frame
        frame = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 1, overlay, 0.5, 0)

        # Display frame
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    
        # Write frame to output video
        out.write(frame)
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Calculate maximum, minimum, and average speed
    if len(speeds) > 0:
        max_speed = max(speeds)
        min_speed = min(speeds)
        avg_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
        print(f"Max speed: {max_speed:.2f} pixels per second")
        print(f"Min speed: {min_speed:.2f} pixels per second")
        print(f"Avg speed: {avg_speed:.2f} pixels per second")
    else:
        print("No speed data available")

    # Release resources
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return output_file       

file_path = 'lift.mp4
BBtracking(file_path)
```

Do I have to change something in VS Code or my python code?

Comment: Your code uses relative paths to files, that could be part of it. Relative paths should usually be avoided.

Comment: @DanGetz OK, that fixed it. Thanks for the super quick reply!

Comment: learn about "current working directory", and learn in which CWD your IDE executes the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works, the thing that was causing the problem was the file location. After I adjusted the path (from a relative path to the full path) it worked fine.